# $_Session "complication" on login and logout php

Tags: php, session, mysqli

I'm doing a database project for university and I'm strugling with a problem in here.
I'm trying to show "log in" when there's no session and "log out" when there is a session.
But actually even after I log in it still shows me "log in" and I tried to print_r($_SESSION); and it tells me that the variable is undefined

I have a logout file:

```
<?php
session_start();
session_destroy();
header("Location:index.php");
?>
```

and a init.php file:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
```

init.php is called when I log in.

Here is a part of index.php:

```
<?php
    require 'db/connect.php';
    require 'functions/security.php';
    ?>

    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Home</title>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/common.css">
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="linking">      
    <?php
    //print_r($_SESSION);
    if (session_status() === PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
        ?>
                    <a href="login.php">Log In</a>           
                    <?php
                } else {
                    ?>
                    <a href="logout.php">Log Out</a>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
                <a href="new_customer.php">Register</a>
                <a href="trips.php">Search for trips</a>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <section id="section">
```

Comment: You have to call `session_start()` iv **every** file. That said, putting `session_start()` in the very beginning of `index.php` will do the trick.

Comment: @AhosanKarimAsik Thats some worse advice

Comment: The thing is I required init.php on the top of index.php and then I always have a session started, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when your login is success on login page.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['user_logged_in'] = true;
```

in your logout page

```
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['user_logged_in']);   
session_destroy();
```

in your home page

```
<?php 
   session_start();
   if(isset($_SESSION['user_logged_in'])) {
 ?>
   < a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>
<?php  
   }
else {
?>
    < a href='login.php'>Login</a>
<?php 
  }
 ?>
```